# Cannot load audio file in tensorflow (Windows10)

Tags: python, windows, audio, tensorflow, ffmpeg

this is may problem.
I can load the audio_binary like this
`audio_binary = tf.read_file(wav_file_path)`
but when I try to read the wav with this:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import ffmpeg
waveform = ffmpeg.decode_audio( audio_binary, file_format='wav', samples_per_second=16000, channel_count=1)
```

I get error `ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.ffmpeg.ops'`

I have also tried doing this:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import audio_ops as contrib_audio
wav_decoder = contrib_audio.decode_wav(audio_binary, desired_channels=1)
```

and I get this error `InvalidArgumentError: Header mismatch: Expected RIFF but found NIST`

By the way I'm using tensorflow-gpu in a Jupyter notebook.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case someone has the same problem.
I was using TIMIT database, and their files, althought their were .wav, the have a differnet codification (NIST). I have to change them to RIFF, like this `forfiles /s /m *.wav /c "cmd /c sph2pipe -f wav @file @fnameRIFF.wav"`
and the use the second command `contrib_audio.decode_wav(...)`

Based on this answer: 
[Change huge amount of data from NIST to RIFF wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370167/change-huge-amount-of-data-from-nist-to-riff-wav-file)

And this page:
http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check what version of tensorflow you currently have.

**tensorflow 1.X:**

```
tensorflow.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio()
```

**tensorflow 2.X:**

```
tensorflow.audio.decode_wav()
```

keep in mind that **decode_wav()** needs the .wav data and cannot read it from the .wav data on it's own

for more information on tensorflow.audio.decode_wav() see documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/audio/decode_wav

check out this answer for more information: [From audio to tensor, back to audio in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675097/from-audio-to-tensor-back-to-audio-in-tensorflow)